# How to access an existing YouTube player that's attached to an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Suppose a player object has been defined from another javascript module `youtube.js` like below:

```
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('initial-video', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

How do I access this `player` from `some_other_js_file.js` so that I can load another video? Is it possible to define a new variable in `some_other_js_file.js` that points to the same player object? If it is not, what could be a possible workaround?

Answer (score 0):

assuming `player` is defined within an iframe, you can access it from the parent page [using its contentwindow property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657399/communication-between-iframes). all global variables within the iFrame will be accesible from the `contentWindow`

from within some_other_js_file.js

```
  youtubeiFrame = document.getElementById('youtube-frame-id').contentWindow;

  alert(youtubeiFrame.player)
```

does this match your situation?

EDIT this answer seems to address [accessing a youtube player from parent iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443578/youtube-iframe-api-how-do-i-control-a-iframe-player-thats-already-in-the-html) with a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/g6P5H/236/)