# linking html file with js file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on one asp page which calls a function in a js file "java_s.js"having parameter a and b .
like this :

```
<button id="abc" onclick= "LoadContent(a,b)"></button>
```

Now there is another asp page which contain an iframe in it and show the content of a html page xyz.html like this   :

```
<iframe src="xyz.html"></iframe>
```

i had included java_s.js file in it . but the problem is when this LoadContent() function is called it is not able to put the content in the div that are defined in xyz.html . So my problem is how to link this js file with the html file .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communication between iFrames?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657399/communication-between-iframes)

Comment: Did you try this same page first?

Comment: if i include this button inside the iframe i had mentioned above . the content is comming inside the iframe . but this button have to be in different page . or if i include that html page in the page where button is . the whole content comes out of the iframe .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> include jquery library
>   Try to add ID to your iframe object like so:

> and in you js file write:

```
function LoadContent(a,b){
return // a , b args
}

$("#abc").live("click",function(){
$("#any").html(LoadContent(a,b));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="xyz.html"></iframe>
```

js: (assume there is a div with id "foo" in xyz.html)

```
var foo = document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.document.getElementById("foo");

var div = document.createElement("div");
foo.appendChild(div);
```

You could also use jQuery, which would require you to write less code.