# Is there a way to inject javascript code from an iframe into the parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, javascript-injection

Is there a way to inject javascript from an iframe into its parent window using javascript? Both the iframe and the parent are in the same domain.

I cannot simply perform the action from the parent window after detecting changes in the iframe, due to other reasons.

example:

```
<div id="bar"> Hello World </div>
<iframe srcdoc="
    <html>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // change "bar"'s style or alter its content
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the global [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) variable in the `iframe`, either by using `window.parent` or `parent` directly.

### Example:

```
<div id="bar"> Hello World </div>
<iframe srcdoc="<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.parent.document.getElementById('bar').style.background = 'red';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>"></iframe>
```

So long as the `iframe` satisfy the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as they're on the same domain. This has been asked before on stack overflow, [see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657399/communication-between-iframes).

In short (from linked thread)

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = 
  top.document.getElementById('otherIframe').contentWindow.
  document.getElementById('someOtherDiv').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how accessing a div from within the iframe using the iframe eventually allows you to alter the parent window?